# How to check if I have two values in an set of values of an table in Databricks Pyspark

Tags: python, performance, pyspark, azure-databricks

Is there any way to change a column based on the presence of two values in a set of values from a databricks pyspark dataframe?

## Example:

```
df = (
    [
        ('E1', 'A1',''), 
        ('E2', 'A2',''),
        ('F1', 'A3',''),
        ('F2', 'B1',''),
        ('F3', 'B2',''),
        ('G1', 'B3',''),
        ('G2', 'C1',''),
        ('G3', 'C2',''),
        ('G4', 'C3',''),
        ('H1', 'C4',''),
        ('H2', 'D1',''),
    ],
    ['old_comp_id', 'db_id', 'comment'] 
)
```

We check for the presence of the values `E1` and `C1,` and we mark with a comment in both cases, and the **expected result** should be:

```
df = (
    [
        ('E1', 'A1','mark'), 
        ('E2', 'A2',''),
        ('F1', 'A3',''),
        ('F2', 'B1',''),
        ('F3', 'B2',''),
        ('G1', 'B3',''),
        ('G2', 'C1','mark'),
        ('G3', 'C2',''),
        ('G4', 'C3',''),
        ('H1', 'C4',''),
        ('H2', 'D1',''),
    ],
    ['old_comp_id', 'db_id', 'comment'] 
)
```

To be able to use multiple workers in Databricks I think it should only use the pyspark framework and not convert to Pandas at any moment.

## Another expected behaviour:

Let's suppose that we do not have the row with the "C1" element. In that case the **input** dataframe would be:

```
df = (
    [
        ('E1', 'A1',''), 
        ('E2', 'A2',''),
        ('F1', 'A3',''),
        ('F2', 'B1',''),
        ('F3', 'B2',''),
        ('G1', 'B3',''),
        ('G3', 'C2',''),
        ('G4', 'C3',''),
        ('H1', 'C4',''),
        ('H2', 'D1',''),
    ],
    ['old_comp_id', 'db_id', 'comment'] 
)
```

and the **output:** would be exactly equal to the **input**.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: I was solving converting to pandas dataframe and looping in the set. To be faster, I employed multiprocessing, which is limited to the driver run in Databricks and does not automatically expand to multiple workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to do this in two steps. First, check if values `C1` and `E1` occur at least once in both columns and if so, then apply the operations, similar to what @Steven suggested:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df = spark.createDataFrame([
        ('E1', 'A1',''), 
        ('E2', 'A2',''),
        ('F1', 'A3',''),
        ('F2', 'B1',''),
        ('F3', 'B2',''),
        ('G1', 'B3',''),
        ('G2', 'C1',''),
        ('G3', 'C2',''),
        ('G4', 'C3',''),
        ('H1', 'C4',''),
        ('H2', 'D1',''),
    ],
    ['old_comp_id', 'db_id', 'comment'] 
)

key_values = ["E1", "C1"]

df_old_comp_id_filtered = df.filter(col("old_comp_id").isin(key_values))
df_db_id_filtered = df.filter(col("db_id").isin(key_values))

if df_old_comp_id_filtered.count() == 0 or df_db_id_filtered.count() == 0:
    df.show() # And preferably return original DF

df.withColumn("comment", when(col("old_comp_id").isin(key_values), "mark").when(col("db_id").isin(key_values), "mark")).show()

# If both key values exist:
+-----------+-----+-------+
|old_comp_id|db_id|comment|
+-----------+-----+-------+
|         E1|   A1|   mark|
|         E2|   A2|       |
|         F1|   A3|       |
|         F2|   B1|       |
|         F3|   B2|       |
|         G1|   B3|       |
|         G2|   C1|   mark|
|         G3|   C2|       |
|         G4|   C3|       |
|         H1|   C4|       |
|         H2|   D1|       |
+-----------+-----+-------+

# Else
+-----------+-----+-------+
|old_comp_id|db_id|comment|
+-----------+-----+-------+
|         E1|   A1|       |
|         E2|   A2|       |
|         F1|   A3|       |
|         F2|   B1|       |
|         F3|   B2|       |
|         G1|   B3|       |
|         G3|   C2|       |
|         G4|   C3|       |
|         H1|   C4|       |
|         H2|   D1|       |
+-----------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: However, to make multiple workers process this solution, I would have to encapsulate in a UDF, right?

Comment: No, the code above it totally parallelizable by Spark - it uses native Spark SQL functions. The only "performance" hot-spot might be the `count` operation, but assuming that filtering that happens before already removes majority of irrelevant rows, then you should be fine with it :)